# Knockout obsevablearry not binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

```
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout'], function (http, app, ko) {

    return {
        displayName: 'Flickr',

        Value: ko.observableArray([]),

        js : $.getJSON("http://localhost:XXXXX/api/File/Get", function (result) {

            self = this;
            self.Value = result;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(self.Value));
//[{"ID":1,"Name":"a","Type":"text","Size":123},{"ID":1,"Name":"a","Type":"text","Size":123},{"ID":1,"Name":"a","Type":"text","Size":123}]

        }),
```

i have the above code in my Drundal SPA application **(flick.js)** and my **(flick.html)** has the following code

```
<ul class="thumbnails" data-bind="foreach: Value">
            <li data-bind=" text: Name ">

            </li>
        </ul>
```

but when i execute this code im not getting the list of name in my html file

what went wrong 
can anyone help me

Comment: Show the code that defines `self` and that calls `applyBindings`.

Comment: @haim770 i can see the  displayName: 'Flickr' on my screen but not the Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the Value observable, not recreate it.
You could also create an object that keeps the 'self' reference.

```
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout'], function (http, app, ko) {
    var VM = function () {
        self = this;
        self.displayName = 'Flickr';
        self.Value = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.js = $.getJSON("http://localhost:XXXXX/api/File/Get", function (result) {
            self.Value(result);
        });
    };
    return new VM();
}),
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems here. The first - you assign value to `observableArray` incorrectly, `observableArray` is a function, so you have to use `()` to assign value to it. The second you have wrong context in self. Move initialization of self to the top of `js` function:

```
define(['plugins/http', 'durandal/app', 'knockout'], function (http, app, ko) {

    return {
        displayName: 'Flickr',

        Value: ko.observableArray([]),

        js : function() {
              var self = this;
              $.getJSON("http://localhost:XXXXX/api/File/Get", function (result) {

                  self.Value(result);
                 console.log(JSON.stringify(self.Value()));
              })
        }}
```

Comment: it is not even going inside the fonction JS and im getting    Navigation Complete[object Object][object Object] 
 Bindingviews/flickr[object Object]   in my console